# What is the difference between STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN and STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW?

Tags: windows, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, buffer-overrun

I just found out that there is a  STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN and a STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW. What's the difference between those 2? I just found [Stack overflow (stack exhaustion) not the same as stack buffer overflow](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2009/01/28/stack-overflow-stack-exhaustion-not-the-same-as-stack-buffer-overflow.aspx) but either it doesn't explain it or I don't understand it. Can you help me out?

Regards
Tobias

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the following stack which grows downward in memory:

```
+----------------+
| some data      |   |
+----------------+   | growth of stack
| 20-byte string |   V
+----------------+
 limit of stack
```

A buffer overrun occurs when you write 30 bytes to your 20-byte string. This corrupts entries further up the stack ('some data').

A stack overflow is when you try to push something else *on* to the stack when it's already full (where it says 'limit of stack'). Stacks are typically limited in their maximum size.

Answer (score 0):

`Stackoverflow` appears when there is no more space in memory to allocate your data, and `buffer overrun` a.k.a. `buffer overflow` is called when program overruns buffer boundary and writes/overwrites data in unexpected part of memory (takes more memory than expected).

**Easily, you can understand this just by reading description of tags [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow/info) and [buffer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/buffer-overflow/info)**.