# Windows 8 application(Windows store app) suddenly terminates

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have created windows store app on windows 8 RTM version. Then I moved the application to run on Windows 8 pro with visual studio 12 Express. upon running the code it gave lot of errors(It was running fluently on RTM version), somehow I removed all errors and application is able to run now. But now as application runs after splash screen it gets interrupted with error saying Windows was unable to communicate with the target application[image]

How can I get rid off this error? What is going wrong? please help me. Thanks in advance.
Here is output of my application

```
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows8         App\mangareader\Application9\bin\Release\AppX\Application9.exe'. 
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open  the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll'. Cannot find or  open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or  open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or  open the PDB file.
The thread 0x1e74 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot  find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded      'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB  file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or   open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or  open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open  the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open  the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open  the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded  'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110_clr0400.dll'. Cannot  find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or  open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll'.  Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or  open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll'
First-chance exception at 0x75564B32 (KernelBase.dll) in Application9.exe: 0x04242420      (parameters: 0x31415927, 0x6E8F0000, 0x007EEE40).
First-chance exception at 0x75564B32 (KernelBase.dll) in Application9.exe: 0x40080201:     WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x80004005, 0x0000003D, 0x050FECE4).
First-chance exception at 0x75564B32 (KernelBase.dll) in Application9.exe: 0x40080201:  WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x80004005, 0x00000055, 0x050FECDC).
First-chance exception at 0x75564B32 (KernelBase.dll) in Application9.exe: 0x40080201:   WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x80004005, 0x00000055, 0x050FF124).
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open  the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded  'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\51e2934144ba15628ba5a31be2dae7dc\m scorlib.ni.dll'. 
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\S ystem.Runtime.dll'. 
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'. 
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\twinapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded  'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB  file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinMetadata\Windows.UI.Xaml.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinMetadata\Windows.UI.Xaml.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinMetadata\Windows.UI.Xaml.winmd'
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. 
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. 
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll'. Cannot  find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ninput.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wininet.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\UIAutomationCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\actxprxy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.Immersive.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dui70.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DWrite.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d2d1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgidebug.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10warp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvwgf2um.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinMetadata\Windows.ApplicationModel.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinMetadata\Windows.ApplicationModel.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinMetadata\Windows.ApplicationModel.winmd'
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MrmCoreR.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\BCP47Langs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application9.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Unhandled exception at 0x5C552A97 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in Application9.exe: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x055CC760, 0x00000003).
Unhandled exception at 0x758F273A (combase.dll) in Application9.exe: 0xC0000602:  A fail fast exception occurred. Exception handlers will not be invoked and the process will be terminated immediately.

STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN encountered
Application9.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
The thread 0x1014 has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 0x1910 has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 0xfe8 has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 0x87c has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 0x1dac has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 0x1924 has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 0xb7c has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 0x17c4 has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 0x14d0 has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 0x16cc has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).The program '[7980]         Application9.exe' has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
Activation of the Windows Store app 'Manga_hy1nbkt9ckjdc!App' failed with error     'Windows was unable to communicate with the target application.  This usually indicates    that the target application's process aborted. More information may be available in the    Debug pane of the Output window (Debug->Windows->Output)'.
```

Comment: There can be exception from `App.xaml.cs`, post the content of output pane.

Comment: I don't want `App.xaml.cs`'s content. Open view menu and then press output, it will open a window. Now run the app so output will show any error if it's available.

Comment: Are you not having an infinite recursion (STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN)? This `Cannot find or open the PDB file` should not be a problem, you can ignore those.

Comment: @BalintBako will you please suggest me how to avoid/ignore this?

Comment: If it is a recursion, that you need to do a code review... It might be a configuration error, then we need more input-

Comment: Are you writing a C++ app? Otherwise it is quite hard to cause this issue with a more managed language...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837134/what-is-the-difference-between-status-stack-buffer-overrun-and-status-stack-over

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3af707f7-ffe0-4801-a154-7e3c06340d2c/statusstackbufferoverrun-encountered

Comment: @BalintBako: I am using c# and XAML(Metro style app)

Comment: Create a new solution/project and copy the sources from the old one to the new one. That usually helps with VS...

Comment: @BalintBako Thank you It's running perfect

Answer (score -1):

Create a new solution/project and copy the sources from the old one to the new one. That usually helps, when you are updating the version of Visual Studio.